# Looking for set of combinatorics problems

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, puzzle

I'm preparing to Mathematics for Computer Science exam. What I learned from past edition of exams is fact of very often occurence of old problems. I mean more or less known problems, but possible to find in some sources. For example "expected number of cycles in permutation", "problem of 100 prisoners" or according to combinatorical proof: "problem of counting specific variations of lattice paths" or "coutnig number of functions with requirements".

Please be so kind to suggest me some websites/textbooks/topics on stack with set of exercises of such a type.

Greetings
M.

Comment: Search for combinatorics, this will give you tons of webpages for courses and math competitions. Most of the courses have problem collections or past exams and such.

Answer (score 3):

MIT has [free lecture notes on combinatorics](http://ocw.mit.edu/high-school/mathematics/combinatorics-the-fine-art-of-counting/lecture-notes/) which are pretty concise and well written. I found it to be a good introduction (and I didn't need to attend the lectures to benefit from it).

Comment: Thanks for that, especially list of additional recources is very helpful! Despite of usefulness of that, I still won't disdain another links :)

Comment: No problem, I'm happy to help

Answer (score 0):

I believe the type of combinatorics probems you are looking for is non-enumerative i.e. you don't need to count the number of objects satisfying a given property, rather you have to understand algorithms, processes, recursions etc.. Note that it will still help to have a good knowledge of enumeratve combinatorics. You should check out *Problem Solving Strategies* by Arthur Engel. It lists huge number of problems on PHP, invariance and monovariance, induction, enumerative combinatorics etc..

You should also check out [this](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h601134) book. It's one of the best that I have seen for olympiad combinatorics which aren't of enumerative type.